# How to restart boost::timer::cpu_timer?

Tags: c++, boost, timer

Looking at [boost::timer::cpu_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html#Class-cpu_timer) definition, I see that it doesn't seem to have any way to restart the timer. Is restarting a cpu_timer can only be done by recreating the timer object, or is there something I'm missing.

Comment: doesn't resume method do what you need?  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html#resume

Comment: resume continues accumulating time, but it doesn't clear the already accumulated time. Or so it sounds to me.

Comment: what about `start()`? As I read the docs it seems to me that it resets the timer. (There would be no need for restart otherwise)

Comment: Huh! Hadn't thought of that! Tested it, and it seems you're right. Stupid of me! :)

Comment: @Elektito ok, I posted it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`start()` restarts the timer, that's why there's no need for a `restart()` function.